# There is something about bell

Tags: meaning

> To his great astonishment, the heavy bell went on from six to seven, and from seven to eight, and regularly up to twelve; then stopped. (A Christmas Carol)

What does it mean? I think the clock is going like 6 to 12. Or isn't it?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the bell is going from 6 to 12. The author phrased it in that way to show that the bell was going number by number, from 6 to 12 in regular intervals. (think number line)

So the bell is ‘jumping’ from 6 to 7, then 7 to 8, then 8 to 9, then 9 to 10, then 10 to 11, then finally 11 to 12 instead of going from 6 to 12 without stopping.

Comment: i am not acquainted with English bell. I can't imagine it. I am foreigner. So can you be more specific? (If it isn't inconvenient, can u include a picture?)

Comment: @ErkhesNyamsaikhan [This video](https://youtu.be/vI1c0dXZS3g?t=55s) shows a tower clock mechanism first playing its *quarter chime* (the chime plays every quarter hour), then striking the bell 12 times, which it does on hours only, for 12 noon.